# finding numbers before letters in word wildcard search

Tags: regex, ms-word

i am looking to find and replace all numbers before a letter in my document to supercript numbers, so expression like "12m" and "12M", but not "12 m" or "12.". i found the right expression [0-9]{1,2}(?=[A-Za-z0-9]) using http://regexr.com/, but the result is different in microsoft word. i thought that changing the "=" to "<" as in [0-9]{1,2}(?<[A-Za-z0-9]) would work, but it doesn't find the right numbers. it finds things like "12 m" and "1-" how do i change the expression i found at regexr to yield the result i am searching for in word?

would my replace look like "\1 "sup" (in brackets) \2"?

thanks in advance.

Comment: MS Word Find and Replace does not support regular expressions. You need to write a macro to use a real regex.

Comment: if wildcards in find and replace is enabled, it supports regular expressions.

Comment: This is a wildcard search and replace, not regex search and replace. See the syntax [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-or-other-items-50b45f26-c4b8-4003-b9e4-315a3547f69c#__toc282602049), it is similar, but not the same as regular expressions.

Comment: ok. now i see. couldn't figure out the difference between the two. but, the problem still stands... that explains why i had to change the "="to a "<", but i should still be able to find the combinations i am looking for using the system in word, which i haven't been able to figure out.

Comment: I suspect that to replace the formatting on one part of the search expression, you will actually need to do a 3-step replace - e.g. find "12m" etc. and replace by 12@@@m (or some such), then find "12@@@" etc. and replace it by the same thing *but with the correct formatting*, then find "12@@@" etc. and replace by 12.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard syntax should be enough for this example, but you need to keep it simple.

`([0-9]{1,2})([a-zA-Z0-9])`

I'm not sure what the replace syntax will be. I don't know know MS Word well enough.

Comment: thanks! i tried that before, but with escaping the brackets, which i thought was necessary.

Comment: the replacement is an issue because you can't only select to replace \1 without also effecting \2 in word. do you know how to write the expression to not choose the following letter as well? i haven't been able to figure that out using this wildcard search.

Answer (score 0):

As bibadia remarks it's not possible for you to perform this search in one step using Word's built-in Find/Replace functionality. While it can FIND, it cannot replace the formatting selectively. For that you'd need to use object model code (VBA/"interop"). Here's some sample code that works on a test document based on the information you provide

```
Sub FindReplaceWithSuperScript()
Dim rng As word.Range
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim sFind As String

Set rng = ActiveDocument.content
sFind = "([0-9]{1;2})([a-zA-Z0-9])"
With rng.Find
    .Text = sFind
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .ClearFormatting
    .wrap = wdFindStop
    bFound = .Execute
    rng.Select
  Do
    If bFound Then
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
        rng.Select
        rng.Font.Superscript = True
    rng.End = ActiveDocument.content.End
    bFound = .Execute(findText:=sFind)
    End If
  Loop While bFound
End With
End Sub
```